# ng-grid with popup edit and save

Tags: angularjs, popup, popupwindow, ng-grid

By using the ng-grid="gridOptions" i can display the data ,my app.js file code is

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
  data: 'myData', 
  enableCellSelection: true,
  enableCellEdit: true,
  enableRowSelection: false,
  columnDefs: [{field: 'name', displayName: 'Name', enableCellEdit: true}, {field:'age', displayName:'Age'}]
};
```

Now how can i get the popup by clicking on the cell data ,in the popup the cell data have to edit and save the changes in grid .Anyone please ...

Comment: Did you try a `cellTemplate`? you could check if the cell equals to yourValue then hook a class that will trigger your popup..... How ever most popup/modal divs are based on `click`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to override your cell template in your edit column templates. columnDefs would be like below

```
var cellTemplate='<div class="ngCellText"  data-ng-model="row"><button data-ng-click="updateSelectedRow(row,$event)">Edit</button></div>'

columnDefs: [{field: 'name', displayName: 'Name', enableCellEdit: true}, 
  {field:'age', displayName:'Age'},
  {field:'',cellTemplate:cellTemplate}   
  ]
```

attach *updateSelectedRow* function to your controller scope,this function gets the first parameter as entire *row* object. you can access all columns by doing **row.entity**. also you can perform two-way binding with **row.entity** object, it updates the grid data whenever it changes.

check out this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/3ikYNarIvasKj4BT76EX?p=preview

Comment: Could you tell me why above plunker is not working ? Thanks.